# String in Haskell that supports UTF-16 and constant time indexing

Tags: string, haskell

I know of bytestring, compactstring, text, and a bunch of other Haskell strings, but I did not find any that supports UTF-16 and constant time indexing, like bytestring does.

Does this exist?

Comment: what about using bytestring with utf16 text values decoded https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.10.0.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html

Comment: UTF-16 does not provide constant-time indexing of unicode codepoints.  In fact, I believe that due to surrogates, no encoding of unicode provides constant-time indexing.

Comment: @Carl, I believe UTF-32 does provide constant-time indexing of codepoints. That doesn't, however, get you constant-time indexing to glyphs.

Comment: It would be more precise to ask for UCS-2, since I am not concerned with surrogates. I am compiling a functional language to Haskell. This language uses 16-bit unicode codepoints, without surrogates. It requires constant time indexing into strings, so I'm looking for the best Haskell library to fit this. It sounds like we have to build our own wrapper around bytestring. We will have to loop to search, because odd-index hits will be invalid, and things like that, but I guess it is managable. Btw. performance of the hand-written test cases are 3 times faster than the same in Java.

Answer (score 2):

The usual `text` interface doesn't support this because it's very rarely useful. However, the package maintainers have continued to use UTF-16 for years despite it being a silly encoding. Therefore, you might be justified in taking a gamble and importing `Data.Text.Internal` to get at the underlying `Array`. That said, this is so rarely the right thing to do that I suspect you may be asking the wrong question. Why do you need this?

Note: this question inspired me to file [an issue](https://github.com/bos/text/issues/133) suggesting that `text` switch to UTF-8. This will likely be denied, but I figured I should mention it.

Comment: There was a GSoC investigating the switch ([proposal](http://jaspervdj.be/files/text.html), [speed measurements](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2011-07-10-text-utf8-initial-results.html), [memory measurements](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2011-08-09-text-utf8-memory-usage.html), [conclusion](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2011-08-19-text-utf8-the-aftermath.html)). In short: there would be a small win, but it would require so much compatibility and testing work that it isn't worth it.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I'm having trouble squaring half the memory for ASCII and cheap I/O in the common case with "small win". What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the actual measurements at the links I posted, which show that you do not get half the memory usage or cheap IO in the common case.

Comment: I am compiling a functional language to Haskell. This language uses 16-bit unicode codepoints, without surrogates. It requires constant time indexing into strings. How stable would the Internal thing be?